# Совершающееся или совершающегося

Tags: причастия

Какое причастие нужно употребить при замене придаточным оборотом в предложении

> Выражает действие, которое совершается не подлежащим.

1. Выражает действие, совершающееся не подлежащим.
2. Выражает действие, совершающегося не подлежащим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильным является первый вариант, так как в оригинальном предложении слово "действие" в винительном падеже:

> Выражает действие, *совершающееся* не подлежащим.

*совершающегося* подразумевает родительный падеж:

> (Нету) действия, совершающегося не подлежащим.

Comment: Выражает (что?) действие, это В.п.

Comment: Согласен, исправил.